# a finite group of order $360$ never has an irreducible character of degree $15$

Tags: finite-groups, characters

The following problem is an exercise in character theory:

"Prove that a finite group of order $360$ never has an irreducible character of degree $15$."

Could you help me for it?

Comment: How advanced an exercise is it? My instinct was to note that unless $G$ has a unique linear character, then the Vanishing-off subgroup of one of degree $15$ would have to be both small and large at the same time (loosely speaking).